# Toggle checkbox only if AJAX returns success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a checkbox in an HTML page, which when toggled displays a Bootstrap modal. The modal has a form with an input field. On form submit, it's sent to a server and the status (success or failure) is returned. If the operation was successful, I want to have the checkbox toggled. If it's a failure, I want the checkbox to remain in the same state as before.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var age = $(this).data('age');
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

And to handle the form submit:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://example.com/foo',
        type:'GET',
        data: 'value=' + value,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#alert').show();            
        }
    });
});
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this instead:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://example.com/foo',
        type:'GET',
        data: 'value=' + value,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $(":checkbox").trigger("click");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why did you use e.preventDefault()

Comment: To avoid default submit action triggered on click of submit button